# Compression is not working in ZLib library

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, zlib

I want to zip a already existing file in a directory, I am calling deflate method

`int def(FILE *source, FILE *dest, int level)` of ZLib library and I'm getting zipped file (making a file with .zip extension), but the problem is when I'm trying to unzip it by double clicking, I'm getting corrupted file though the return value is `Z_OK`.

PS: want to compress file not data. Any Help???

Answer (score 0):

zlib does not produce the zip format.  You would need to generate your own zip headers and trailers around the deflate compressed data produced by zlib.

Comment: The [zlib source distribution](http://www.zlib.net/) does include contributed source for creating zip archives.  If you're the same Mark Adler who maintains the zlib site, you must know that, so I'm surprised you didn't mention it.

Comment: It is a contribution to zlib that I don't provide support for.  There are other choices that may be better, such as libzip and libarchive.

Comment: @MarkAdler - I'm not very sure about  generating own zip header and trailers ,if you could elaborate a bit more ,that would be great help.

Comment: I recommend that you use an existing library, such as [libarchive](http://www.libarchive.org/).  If you want to write your own code, then you'll need to read the [zip format description](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).